# Pip suddenly does not work in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pypy

I'm working on a project. I've created a `virtualenv` and installed a couple of packages. After working on a project for a while, `pip` started to raise exceptions.

Global `pip` works without problem.

This is in a `Django` project where I worked on `AJAX` post (`csrf_token` exempt).
It raises the error everytime I type `pip install *`

```
(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\diplomova_praca\PriceCheckingProject>pip
install django-tables2
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 245, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 71, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 316, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 117, in user_agent
    json=json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"), sort_keys=True),
KeyError: 'post_data'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\diplomova_praca\PriceCheckingProject\ven
v\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 217, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 247, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 71, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 316, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "c:\users\milano\pycharmprojects\diplomova_praca\pricecheckingproject\ven
v\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 117, in user_agent
    json=json.dumps(data, separators=(",", ":"), sort_keys=True),
KeyError: 'post_data'
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell or give you an answer to your problem just from this info. Have you tried to make a new a env and install the requirements like `pip install -r requirements.txt` as normally?

Comment: Right now, I removed whole venv and created a new. I wasn't able even pip freeze

Comment: You don't need to remove it at first. You could check `ENV/lib/Pythonx/site-packages` and get wich packages were installed. Did you succeed?

Comment: @Milano You added the `pypy` tag. Is this question pypy-specific?